# Spring Boot YAML configuration with URL in key no longer loads correctly with version 2

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm migrating my application from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0 and one of the YAML properties no longer loads correctly. The following configuration snippet:

```yaml
myapp
  serviceUrls:
    'https://example.org/test': 'https://test.example.org/Endpoint'
```

is mapped to this configuration class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public final class MyAppProperties {
  private Map<String, String> serviceUrls = new HashMap<>();
  //[...]
}
```

- With Spring Boot 1.5, it loads as a map with `https://example.org/test` -> `https://test.example.org/Endpoint`;
- but with Spring Boot 2.0, the colons and slashes disappear from map keys `httpsexample.orgtest` -> `https://test.example.org/Endpoint`.

I couldn't find any mention of this in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide). Has YAML parsing changed in Spring Boot 2? Is there a better way to write YAML maps with URLs as keys?

Comment: Hane you tried double quotes or backslashes? YAML syntax is surprising sometimes.

Comment: @KonstantinPelepelin Yes, I tried both and my key still gets mangled. It's weirder since the same string fed to `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml#load` does produce the expected result...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I should have checked GitHub issues... someone reported [a similar problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13404). The solution is to use the "bracket syntax", which is unfortunately [barely documented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding), wrapping the keys within brackets:

```
myapp
  serviceUrls:
    '[https://example.org/test]': 'https://test.example.org/Endpoint'
```