# Spring Boot 2 - YAML keys with special characters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am upgrading my application from SpringBoot 1.5 to 2.3, the old application had the following yml file

```
config:
 pic_code:
  "Test/Try": "ABC"
  "Trial": "DRF"
```

After upgrading, YAML key with '/' is not being read properly and gives null.

I have tried to change the key as below

```
"[Test/Try]"
'[Test/Try]'
"Test'/Try"
```

but nothing worked.

Any suggestions will be very much helpful

Comment: Does this solve the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910550/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-with-url-in-key-no-longer-loads-correctly-with-ve

Comment: The following entry should work: `'[Test/Try]': "ABC"`.

Comment: I have checked the above link already and tried the same but it didn't work for me

Comment: can you show code how you are reading it ?

Comment: Apologies, it works, I missed changing test yml files.  Thank you all for the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `'[Test/Try]'` as per the link shared above [Spring Boot YAML configuration with URL in key no longer loads correctly with version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910550/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-with-url-in-key-no-longer-loads-correctly-with-ve)